# Como remover um link de uma string em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Como posso fazer para remover o link de uma string em JavaScript?

```
str = "hey olha isso http://google.com.br, legal né?"
var test = str.description.replace(/.*?:///g, "");
```

Resultado esperado:

> hey olha isso, legal né?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode usar esta expressão regular.

```js
var urlPattern = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/g;
var textoComUrl = "hey olha isso http://google.com.br/, legal né?";
var textoSemUrl = textoComUrl.replace(urlPattern, "");
console.log(textoSemUrl);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = test.description.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para a URL da pergunta, as outras respostas servem bem, mas vale lembrar que uma URL pode ser muito mais complicada do que os exemplos citados.

Por exemplo, ela pode ser algo como `https://www.abc.com/xyz/a,b?x=aa%20b&y=1,2` ou `http://www.abc.com/xyz#teste-bla` (repare que [a vírgula pode aparecer em algumas partes da URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199286)). E tentar fazer uma regex que contemple qualquer URL válida [é bem complicado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738).

Em vez de tentar fazer uma regex monstruosa (como as do [link já indicado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738)), eu sugiro tentar uma mais simples, que extrai os trechos que **parecem** uma URL, e aí você valida usando a [interface `URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) (que é feito para isso). Se for válida, aí você remove. Algo assim:

```js
var str = "hey olha isso http://google.com.br, essa é inválida: http:///// - essa é válida: https://www.abc.com/xyz/a,b?x=aa%20b&y=1,2, essa também http://www.abc.com/xyz#teste-bla e http://127.0.0.1:8080/app legal né?";
var semURL = str.replace(/https?:\/\/([^ ,]|,(?! ))+/g, function (match) {
    try {
        // se for válida, não cai no catch
        new URL(match);
        return ''; // remove a URL da string
    } catch {
        // não é uma URL válida, não faz a substituição
        return match;
    }
});
console.log(semURL);
```

Com isso o resultado será:

```
hey olha isso , essa é inválida: http:///// - essa é válida: , essa também  e  legal né?
```

Eu usei uma regex mais simples para extrair trechos que se parecem com URL's. No caso, pode ser qualquer coisa que comece com `http` ou `https` (pois o `s?` indica que a letra "s" é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)). Depois temos `://` e em seguida temos a parte mais complicada: `[^ ,]|,(?! )`.

O `|` indica [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), com duas opções:

- `[^ ,]` - qualquer caractere que não seja espaço ou vírgula, **ou**
- `,(?! )` - uma vírgula, desde que não tenha um espaço depois

Assim, no trecho `http://google.com.br,` eu não removo a vírgula, e nos demais eu pego tudo até o próximo espaço. Depois, no `replace` eu uso uma função que analisa o trecho que foi encontrado, e decide qual será a substituição feita. Se for uma URL válida, eu substituo por `''` (string vazia), que é o mesmo que remover. Se não for uma URL válida, eu retorno o próprio *match* encontrado, ou seja, ela não será substituída e permanecerá no texto original.

A regex da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83191/112052) não considera o trecho da *query string* que está depois da vírgula (que, lembrando, [é válido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199286)), além de não remover o hash `#teste-bla` da última URL. E ela também não remove `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app`.

Claro que ainda sim esta regex pode falhar. Como a vírgula é um caractere válido em URL's, pode ser que ele de fato seja o último, então teria que ser removido (mas aí não teria como saber se ele faz parte ou não do link). Enfim, tudo depende dos casos que você tem.